# Prevent MDI window to appear in the Window menu list

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mdi

I have a .NET MDI application that uses the [MDI Window List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171654.aspx) to automatically populate child MDI forms into the Window menu.

Is it possible to prevent certain MDI child forms not be included in this automatic menu list?

Requirements:
 - This child form has to be an MDI child.
 - This forms is always at the bottom of the MDI form stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle the DropDownOpening event of the menu item, and remove the unwanted item from the list. Something like this:

```
MenuStrip ms = new MenuStrip();
ToolStripMenuItem windowMenu = new ToolStripMenuItem("Window");
ms.MdiWindowListItem = windowMenu;

windowMenu.DropDownOpening += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (windowMenu.DropDownItems.Count > 0)
                windowMenu.DropDownItems.RemoveAt(0);
        };

ms.Items.Add(windowMenu);
ms.Dock = DockStyle.Top;            
this.MainMenuStrip = ms;
this.Controls.Add(ms);
```