# WinForms - MenuStrip - WindowsMenu - Increasing Number of Active Forms Displayed

Tags: winforms, menustrip

When there are more than 9 active forms open the 'More Windows' option appears.

I would like to increase the number of active forms listed in the WindowsMenu to more than 9 being displayed.

Is there a way to set this programmatically or in design time?

[Screenshoot of Windows Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHzUr.jpg)

Comment: check this out:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425221/prevent-mdi-window-to-appear-in-the-window-menu-list

Comment: or you could build a solution where you use the answer [here][1]: to get your all the submenuitems and then recreate the menu and manually add all the windows.


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33766276/cannot-get-all-the-submenu-items-in-winform-in-c-sharp

Comment: No, it is hard-coded [in source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/MdiWindowListStrip.cs,88).  Not unreasonable btw.